# How, with reflection, can I set an assembly to be 32-bit (i.e. x86)

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

I know I can use [CORFLAGS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  to force a .NET assembly to 32-bits. How can I do it when I am using reflection to create the assembly in the first place? There seems to be a function to get the value ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.getpekind.aspx )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how to set this for a dynamic assembly generated using `AssemblyBuilder`, then you can use [an overload of `AssemblyBuilder.Save()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145516.aspx) that lets you specify this.

Comment: Fantastic - not quite sure how I missed it though :)